# APT problems after attempting to upgrade from Ubtuntu 17.04 to 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

Today I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu version from 17.04 to 18.04 following [this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-16-10-17-04-to-ubuntu-18-04), but this didn't work:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign.:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bonic InRelease
Ign.:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bonic-updates InRelease
Ign.:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bonic-backports InRelease
Ign.:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bonic Release
Ign.:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bonic-security InRelease
Ign.:6 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bonic-updates Release
...
```

I followed all steps, but `sudo apt-get update` gives me these errors. How can I revert these changes to first update to Artful and then Bionic?

Comment: That unofficial tutorial leads you down an unwise and unsupported path. DO NOT use it unless you are expert at package management. That method of upgrade is appropriate for Debian...but not for Ubuntu. Since the upgrade windows for 17.04 and 17.10 have closed, and since many changes have been made since 17.04, the *tested and supported* solution is to backup your data and clean-install from an 18.04 or 18.10 LiveUSB. Note that the specific error you are asking about seems due to a typo you made - spelling matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first undo what ever you have done before such as

**You spelled bionic as bonic so:**

undo

```
sudo sed -i 's/<whatever>/bonic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

by running

```
sudo sed -i 's/bonic/<whatever>/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Open the **Software & Updates** settings in **System Settings**.

or

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Select the **Updates** tab

Set it to *For long-term support versions* if you are using 17.10.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
update-manager -c
```

Update Manager should open up and tell you that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is now available.

Comment: Note that Kasprian misspelled 'bionic', so the second undo 'sed' command will fail him.

Comment: Thanx [@user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) for the observation.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was very nervous today, because my personal laptop went down and i have to send it to service(problem with LCD panel). As a result I had to configure my sisters laptop ASAP to end my project. Thank you all for help.

Comment: Thanx [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna)